# Abelian hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

Is there any way to tell from its defining equation when an affine hypersurface has a group law? I am aware that all such groups are matrix groups; in that case I might want to ask when a variety over $k$ admits a free and transitive action by an algebraic group over $k$? What necessary and sufficient conditions do we know of in low dimensions/arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: Elliptic curves are not affine. I believe all affine group schemes are actually matrix groups (this is in Waterhouse's book iirc)

Comment: Right, thanks for that! I'm aware they are all matrix groups; maybe I should rewrite my question in those terms.